# CSS Glow on focus textarea is not working correctly

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm designing a website and run into trouble on my css I'm kinda new on this css thing and its kinda weird that the css rule I made for input text is not working correctly on my text area here is my css

```
input[type="text"], textarea {
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
        border: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 2%;
        color: white;
    }
    input[type=text]:focus, textarea:focus {
             box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #f2dede inset, 0px 0px 8px #dff0d8;


    }
```

and this is how it looks like on the browser
[image]

the text field Name has the correct glow but its weird that the textarea is not considering that they both have the same rule as what I pasted on my code above..

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the following:

```
input[type=text]:focus, textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #f2dede inset, 0px 0px 8px #dff0d8;
  outline: none;
}
```

Some browsers set an outline on inputs, text areas etc on focus automatically and this most probably is the cause of your problem. Setting the outline to `none` should remove this behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

this is because input has default style,when set your style,you can reset focus style:

```
    *:focus {outline: none;}
```